# Remove 'hidden' images from UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scrollView that shows images set by url. Now I only want the visible image and the previous and next image to be pre-loaded onto the scrollView to reduce memory usage. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? +May be you can use UICollectionView instead of "raw" scroll view and so will get reuse function out of the box

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `UITableView` instead of a `UIScrollView`, you can create your own `UITableViewCell` type which loads 1 image in its content.

The advantage is that only the visible `UITableViewCells` (those currently displaying on the  device's screen) are loaded into the system memory, so it won't use too much resources.

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) is one of the many CustomCell Tutorials you will find on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

When I did the same I created a UIScrollView of 3 times the size. Just big enough to hold the 3 images, the one that is currently displayed and the next siblings to the right and the left.

Those images are pre-loaded if they have not been loaded before. So the user has some smooth and responsive look & feel.

When the user scrolls to the next one, and he can scroll for one only, then I re-arrange the view. Lets say images 1, 2 and 3 are in the scroll view and 2 is visible, so 1, 2 and 3 are (pre-)loaded. The user scrolls to the right. Image 3 will be visible. As soon as it becomes fully visible I set the visible rect of the scroll view to the middle again. Now Image 2 is the left most one, image 3 is visible and image 4 is placed as the right most one and pre-loaded.

When the end of the list of images is reached, meaning when the 1st or last one are displayed, then I place a dummy view on the left most or right most place respectivly that is a simple text view showing "no more images".

Unfortunately I cannot share that code.

Comment: Yeah I got something like this working already, my problem is removing the images that are not visible.. Too bad you can't share some code because that would really help me out

Comment: No, the code would not really help because it is "embedded" into some rather difficult business logic and I made some conceptual mistakes there as that was my first real app. What problem do you have removing the images? I used some kind of app internal memory cache where I kept them in a dictionary and when memory warnings come in I delete the oldest half in that dictionary. In the meantime I learned of better solutions for caching. But what is your specific problem removing them?